# the while loop does not stop when the condition has already been met

Tags: c

In my code, I want to create three threads one by one. So I use a global variable to control this. But it does not work as I design. It is blocked on a while loop. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int startb = 0, startc=0;

.......

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pthread_t ida,idb,idc;
    int result;

    pthread_key_create(&stKey, TsdFree);

    result = pthread_create(&idb, NULL, (void*)printB, NULL);
    if(0 != result)
    {
        printf("create thread B error\n");
    }
    while (1 != startb); /*block here*/
    result = pthread_create(&idc, NULL, (void*)printC, NULL);
........
}
```

Thread B:

```
void  printB(void* para)
{
   for(int i=0; i<2;++i)
   {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       startb = 1;
       pthread_cond_wait(&conda, &mutex);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      printf("B\n");
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       pthread_cond_signal(&condb);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I use gdb to see the value of the variable of startb. it turns out that the value of startb has already been 1:

> > Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db
> >     library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1". 0x000000000040068b
> >     in main (argc=, argv=) at pthread.c:57
> >     57      while (1 != startb); (gdb) bt
> >
> > ## 0  0x000000000040068b in main (argc=, argv=) at pthread.c:57 (gdb) p startb $1 = 1 (gdb) bt
> >
> > ## 0  0x000000000040068b in main (argc=, argv=) at pthread.c:57 (gdb) c
>
> Continuing.

The Call stack of these threads:

main:

```
[<0>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x59/0xd0
[<0>] prepare_exit_to_usermode+0x77/0x80
[<0>] retint_user+0x8/0x8
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

thread B:

```
[<0>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x120
[<0>] futex_wait+0x10a/0x250
[<0>] do_futex+0x325/0x500
[<0>] SyS_futex+0x13b/0x180
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Please add the declaration of startb so we can help better.

Comment: @iosi G  the startb is a global variable. The declaration has been added.

Comment: regarding: `void  printB(void* para)`  The signature of a posix thread is `void * printB( void* para)`  Note the return type is `void*` not `void`

Comment: OT: in `main()` when the parameters are not used, avoid the two warnings from the compiler about unused parameters by using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output MANY warning and error messages.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to perform the same thing

Comment: the posted code often mentions the variable `mutex`, but never actually declares that variable.  Suggest, outside of any function use: `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

Comment: the posted code starts a thread named `printC()` but there is no function with that name.

Comment: the posted code references the two variables: `conda` and `condb` but those variables are never declared anywhere in the posted code.  Please post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem, so we can help you

Answer (score 5):

You can't use *simple* variables for inter thread communication. As is stands, the compiler will see that in the loop

```
while (1 != startb); /*block here*/
```

the value of `startb` never is modified, and hence will *legally* rewrite it internally to

```
if( 1 != startb ){
    while( true );
}
```

A loop waiting for some externally set flag is called a *[Spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock)* and a proper spinlock implementation must take care to use *[Atomic Semanticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_semantics)* and *[Memory Barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)*.

However for what you intend to do, the right choice is the use of a *[Condition Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables_2)*, a construct that's perfectly well supported by pthreads, which you're already attempt do use, but do it improperly.

Comment: Ah ，I see. Thanks a lot.